# For What Value of P is $\sum (-1)^{n-1}\frac{(\ln(n))^p}{n}$ convergent?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

**The Question**

for what value of p is $\sum (-1)^{n-1}\frac{(\ln(n))^p}{n}$ convergent?

**My Work**

It's an alternating series, so I have to show which p values it's limit to infinity go to $0$ and I have to show for what values of p it is decreasing.

*Showing which Values it is decreasing on*

I first worked out the derivative $\ln(n)^{p-1}(p - \ln(n))$ then I think I showed that for all $p<\ln(n)$ it is less than $0$.

*Showing where the limit is 0*

This appears to be true for all values of $p>0$. Using L'hospital's rule we can constantly reduce this problem to some prouduct of $(\ln(n)^{p-something}*p+something)/n$. Eventually $p-something = 1$ and L'hospital's rule will evaluate the limit to zero. Tests on wolframalpha support this.

**My Problem**

I'm not very sure I did this question correctly. The part about showing value it is decreasing on, I think my book would want a more exact answer. I'm not really sure how to interpret $p<\ln(n)$. I also don't know if my explanation for the limit going to $0$ was correct and if it was I would like to know how to explain it more mathematically.

Comment: So, for all large enough $n$, that is whenever $n>e^p$, the common term is decreasing by absolute value (which is what you need). Perhaps there are finitely many $n$ at the beginning for which this does not hold, but you may split yous series into: (a) this finite sum at the beginning, and (b) the rest of it, where the common term decreases by absolute value, so the rest if convergent, so adding the finitely many term at the beginning, it remains convergent.

Comment: What about the part with the limit? Was I right on that too?

Comment: yes, applying L'Hospital rule enough many times is right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f(x) = \dfrac{\ln^p x}{x} \to f'(x) = \dfrac{p(\ln x)^{p-1} - \ln^p x}{x^2} = \dfrac{(\ln x)^{p-1}}{x^2}\cdot (p-\ln x) < 0 \iff p < \ln x \iff e^p < x$. This shows that starting at some index $n > e^p$, the series converges conditionally for all $p$'s.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know if the limit part of my argument is correct?

Comment: It is not correct because $p - \text{something}$ may never be $1$. So you need to consider $p > 0$ and $p < 0$. For the first case, apply enough times L'hospital rule to get it to negative and you are done.

Comment: Okay so for $p<0$ we have $\frac{1}{(\ln(x)^p)x}$ that goes to $0$ so we can say this series converges for all values of $p$ where $e^p<x$?

Comment: That is certainly true.