# At what values of P does this series converge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

For what values of $p$ does the series

$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}{(-1)}^n \frac{ {(\ln n)}^p }{n}$$

converge?
Using the alternating series test the only way I made the it diverge was when I replaced $p$ with $n$, so is there no number that makes the series diverge?
Do all numbers make the series converge?
I used desmos [image: desmos] and set up a slider for $p$ and tried to make the limit as $n$ goes to infinity do anything other than go to $0$ (alternating series test says if it goes to $0$ then it converges), but if I scrolled out enough it always went to $0$.

So my question is: $(1)$ Is there a value of p that makes the series diverge (limit disregarding the $-1$ go to anything other than $0$) or do all values of $p$ make this go to $0$ and therefore the series always converges? $(2)$ How would you figure out what that number is (assuming it exists)?

Comment: You already mentioned the alternating series test. What does it imply for a fixed $p$? (Setting $p = n$ is not allowed.)

Comment: This question is very similar to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1018006/for-what-value-of-p-is-sum-1n-1-frac-lnnpn-convergent (I would have commented this, but I don't have enough reputation)

Comment: This is an entire function because $O(\ln(n)^p)\le O(n)$ for a given $n$ and so the ratio decreases and hence the series converges...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any fixed $p$, the sequence $\frac{(\ln n)^p}n$ is eventually decreasing, and so by Leibniz, the series $\sum_n(-1)^n\frac{(\ln n)^p}n$ converges.

Comment: (And one may test it is eventually decreasing by differentiating $(\ln x)^p/x$, say.)

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{ {(\ln n)}^p }{n}$ is a limit of type $\infty/\infty$ so we may apply L'Hôpital.
We'll get

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{ {(\ln n)}^p }{n}
=
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{ {p(\ln n)}^{p-1} }{n}
$$

We can repeat this process until the exponent becomes $0$ or less, at which point it should be clear the answer will be $0$.